# How to log in to a remote rails application using devise, omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, devise, omniauth

I have two applications, AppA and AppB, they are both Rails applications.

I have created a single sign-on mechanism using Devise, Omniauth and Doorkeeper.
This is where if you are logged into AppA, then you will be authorised to AppB, since AppB makes a oauth call to AppA to check this. AppA has devise and currently you have to login there.

What I would like to be able to do is to create an ajax login form in AppB, and this would pass my credentials to Devise in AppA and give me access to AppB, instead of redirecting to appA and back.

I seem to be able to do this OK if I disable CSRF checking in AppA, but I would like to be able to have an alternative where I either don't have to do this, or I can provide an alternative without any security holes.

So my main question is if anyone has any idea how to do this, or if they have done something similar and have suggestions?
Many Thanks,

Eamon

Answer (score 0):

You could disable CSRF checking in your API controller (leaving it in your ApplicationController so the rest of your app is protected) with, e.g.:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

Or if you only want to disable CSRF checking for certain actions, add the following to your controller, for example:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:new, :create]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I want to ensure I have some security on this, so I don't just want to take away the CSRF and leave nothing in it's place.

Comment: As I mentioned above - you'll want to disable CSRF checking in your ApiController *only*. You can then leave CSRF protection enabled in your ApplicationController by default so the rest of your app is protected.